# Right Schema.org vocabulary for top search query on my site

Tags: schema.org

I have a Web Site where at the bottom I show the most searched keywords in the site. This keyword are all physical locations.

You know if there is a schema on Schema.org vocabulary for add meaning to this items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keywords are linked, each of the linked pages could be a [`SearchResultsPage`](http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage).

For the links to these pages:

[`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) defines the property [`relatedLink`](http://schema.org/relatedLink), but it’s questionable if the top search phrases are really related to each of your web pages (I’d say they are not). And note this property expects a URL, not a `WebPage` (or `SearchResultsPage`) item.
Apart from `relatedLink`, there doesn’t seem to be a property that would be suitable for referencing (links to) top search phrases.

If you want to mark it up as some kind of list, you could use [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) (I’d only go this way if you think the list is important). Note that you can’t use `relatedLink` in combination with that.

**tl;dr:** Use `SearchResultsPage` for the search result pages. Leave the footer links to these search result pages alone.